# Is it possible to validate if generic object and not function, array string and so on

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to check if an object is just a simple {} with key:value pairs and not a function, array, string number and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this [with `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (although watch out for `null`).

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(x) == Object.prototype` should do it, however I'm not sure *why* you want to check this.